# How does one enable deepviews previews on Branch.io?

Tags: branch.io

I've enabled deepviews already, but our Branch-generated links are not bringing us to the deepviews' previews.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is Vatsal from Branch.

Here are a few points to take note of:

- Make sure you have enabled the Deepviews for the same platform as the one you are testing on.
- Make sure your app is not installed already, or else the Branch links will open the app and not the Deepview.
- Make sure you are not using any [custom fallbacks](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#redirections) which overrides the default deepview.

If you are still not able to resolve the issue. Can you please write us at `integrations@branch.io?` And we help you solve the issue faster!

Thanks.

Comment: Vatsal, I managed to get deepviews working for desktop but not for iOS and Android. Do you know what I might be doing wrong?